# How to make print statement order change depending on the option you pick first

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print statement to change depending on what answer you choose first.And you only have a set number of chances.

For example you have three choices A, B & C. If you choose A FIRST  it would say,  "That is wrong" and if you choose B as the SECOND it would say"That is still wrong, if you choose C "Are you even trying?.

But I you Choose B or C FIRST It would say "That is wrong" first. Depending on what you choose first, second or third the print would change

```
for tries in range(3):

    Response = input("""Response

A)Love 

B)Dog

C)Cast

D)Blowerfish""")

    if Response != "A" or Response != "a":
        print("That is wrong")
        break
    elif: Response != "A" or Response != "a"
        print("That is still wrong")

    elif: Response != "A" or Response != "a"
        print("Are you even trying")
    else:
        print("Out of Chances")
```

How can I get it to work or what do I have to add or change to make it work the way I want.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `tries` in your if-else logic.

```
if Response != "A" or Response != "a":
    if tries == 0:
        print("That is wrong")
    elif tries == 1:
        print("That is still wrong")
    elif tries == 2:
        print("Are you even trying")
```

Comment: You can also use `if Response.lower() != "a":`

Answer (score 0):

Use the index of the current iteration (tries) to decide which error message to show. This could be done with a clunky if statement, or you could nearly retrieve the message from a list - this is preferable.

```
prompt = 'a, b, or c: ' #your multi-line input string
err_messages = ['That is wrong', 'That is still wrong','Are you even trying?']
for tries in range (3):
    response = input(prompt)
    if response.lower() == 'd':
        print('you got it right')
        break
    elif response.lower() in 'abc':
        print(err_messages[tries])
    else:
        print('invalid choice')
```

*I also renamed capitalised variables to lowercase as capitalisation is conventionally reserved for class names*

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I understand your question correctly, but if you are trying to make the message different for every try, you can do:

```
try_counter = 0 # Initialize try_counter 
while try_counter < 3: # Ask until user is out of chances
  Response = input('...')
  if Response not in "Aa": # if Response isn't 'A' or 'a'
    print((
      'That is wrong', 
      'That is still wrong', 
      'Are you even trying'
    )[try_counter]) # Create a tuple/list of messages and select the one on index of try_counter, so when try_counter is 0, it will select the fist message etc.
    try_counter += 1 # Move to next chance. 
  else: 
    print('That is correct! ')
    break # We don't want to ask again if the answer is correct
if not try_counter < 3: # This will be executed only if the cycle was left because of the given rule.
  print('Out of Chances')
```

Python doesn't care about if some if block was already executed, so I it is always using the first case. You count the tries instead and select the message by a try counter and print the message.

Comment: You understood what I was trying to do thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should read more about if statements and loops. Your current implementation loops through the same if statements three times. Currently the loop always stops at the first if statement orngoes straight to else if your response is a, because you are comparing the same thing three times. You should remove the break statement unless you want to exit the loop early. Easy way to fix this would be adding your tries variable to all of the if statements so that it compared the amount of tries in addition to the response, e.g if (Response != ”A” or Response != ”a” ) and tries == 0: .This isn’t very pretty way to achieve this, but it should get you started.

You also have : in the wrong place on your elif statement, it should be at the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It is very insightful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your syntax `elif:` is wrong, you should use `:` at the end. 
Example: `elif Response != "A" or Response != "a":`
On the other hand, to achieve what you've asked, you need to save first input and check with newer input then conclude something on elif such as `elif response is not "A" for 2 times or more`